# Read strings from keyboard in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to read a string from keyboard but i don't know why isn't working, I tried a lot of methods, but nothing worked! Can someone help me or give me an idea?

```
type Polinom = [Int]    
scriePolinom :: Polinom -> String
....
main = do  
    a<-getLine
    --let a=[2,-5,1] 
    scriePolinom a
```

Comment: `main` is required to have type `IO ()`, but `scriePolinom a` has type `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the line into the corresponding data:

```
import Data.List
parseIntList :: String -> [Int]
parseIntList s = [read x :: Int | x <- words s]

type Polinom = [Int]    
scriePolinom :: Polinom -> String
....
main = do  
    a <- getLine
    let intlist = parseIntList a
    putStrLn $ scriePolinom intlist
```

Comment: `parseIntList :: String -> [Int]
parseIntList s = [read x :: Int | x <- words s]

main=do 
    {
        a <- getLine
        scriePolinom (parseIntList a)}`

Comment: "The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression
      a <- getLine scriePolinom (parseIntList a)" I don't get it why!

Comment: @Bob, you are on the IO monad, so you have to do something with it, mostly print it, ill add to the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :type getLine   -- you can also write :t getLine
getLine :: IO String
```

This tells you that `getLine` always gives you (after doing some kind of impure I/O operations, in this case *waiting for the user to enter some stuff on the keyboard, until pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>*) a value of type `String`. Which makes sense: a string, also called...

```
Prelude> :info String   -- you can also write :i String
type String = [Char]    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

...*list of characters*. These are just the exact characters/keys the user typed in. In general, these characters may *not* properly describe a `Polinom` – what, for example, if the user enters `34958oiyq4ulbwre`?

What you need to do is trying to *parse* the input string to a more meaningfully-typed value, like `Polinom`. How to do that depends on what form you actually expect the input to be. If the user should use normal Haskell syntax for the coefficients, e.g. `[2, -5, 1]`, you can use the standard [`read`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read) parser:

```
Prelude> scriePolinom (read "[2, -5, 1]")
"[2,-5,1]"
```

Or if, as [Daniel Sanchez assumes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43718776/745903), you expect just a sequence of space-separated numbers in decimal notation, you can first split up these numbers as *words*, then read each one individually:

```
Prelude> scriePolinom . map read $ words "2 -5 1"
"[2,-5,1]"
```

To use this in an executable program, you can use the ready-build combination of `getLine` and `read`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do  
    a <- readLn
    putStrLn $ scriePolinom a
```

Note that `read`/`readLn` are not robust with respect to malformed input (they're not *total functions*) – this will just crash the program unless you wrap it in explicit exception handling. For serious applications I recommend using a full-featured parsing library, such as [megaparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec).

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

```hs
f l=[b|(a,b)<-zip[x<'b'|x<-'a':l]l,a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hxzY6qUYjUSdJ00a3KrMgusJGPUm9psJGVz1R3SonNkcnMfZ/bmJmnoKtQko@l4JCcUmRgo2uQnpqiU9mXipQoKC0JBgoppEGktL8n5GelpqSnJQIJnKyszJhAsjs/LxcZK5CeVlpSXFRYQGaOBoXUwEyG4QB)